# Pandas: wrong values written in a DataFrame using .loc: bug or misunderstanding?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I would like to modify the content of an excel file based on the values inside of a Python dictionary. I am using the .loc function but for some mysterious reason, it works every second time, the other time it writes the column names instead of the values I want to write. Has anyone an input on this:

```
dict_test={"a":"A","b":1}
df_xxx=pd.DataFrame(columns=["a","b"])
df_xxx.loc["xxx"]={"a":dict_test["a"],"b":dict_test["b"]}
print("DataFrame written to excel:")
print(df_xxx)
df_xxx.to_excel("df_xxx.xlsx") 

#####
print("######")
df_xxx=pd.read_excel("df_xxx.xlsx",index_col=0)
print("DataFrame read from excel:")
print(df_xxx)
df_xxx.loc["xxx"]={"a":dict_test["a"],"b":dict_test["b"]}
print("DataFrame after modification - > written to excel:")
print(df_xxx)
df_xxx.to_excel("df_xxx.xlsx")

#####
print("######")
df_xxx=pd.read_excel("df_xxx.xlsx",index_col=0)
print("DataFrame read from excel:")
print(df_xxx)
df_xxx.loc["xxx"]={"a":dict_test["a"],"b":dict_test["b"]}
print("DataFrame after modification:")
print(df_xxx)
```

output:

```
DataFrame written to excel:
     a  b
xxx  A  1
######
DataFrame read from excel:
     a  b
xxx  A  1
DataFrame after modification - > written to excel:
     a  b
xxx  a  b      => why is it written a and b and not A and 1?????
######
DataFrame read from excel:
     a  b
xxx  a  b
DataFrame after modification:
     a  b
xxx  A  1      => why are this time the values A and 1?????
```

Answer (score 1):

Just ran your code into my Jupyter. Does work ok:

```
DataFrame written to excel:
     a  b
xxx  A  1
######
DataFrame read from excel:
     a  b
xxx  A  1
DataFrame after modification - > written to excel:
     a  b
xxx  A  1
######
DataFrame read from excel:
     a  b
xxx  A  1
DataFrame after modification:
     a  b
xxx  A  1
```

Have you tried to do:

```
print(df_xxx.loc["xxx"])
```

after the first modification ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer:
print(df_xxx.loc["xxx"]) returns :
a    a
b    b
Name: xxx, dtype: object

This is probably a bug in my Pandas version (1.0.5)

Comment: Yes, that was my initial guess as well. Let us know if upgrading solved your issue...